# How many apple push notification certificate can create in both (development and distribution)

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How many apple push notification certificate can create in both (development and distribution), because I am getting error [image]

Comment: If you want to create a push notification certificate then why are you trying to create an iOS App Development certificate?

Comment: You need to go for the `Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)` option

Comment: At the moment I know you can only create 2 tokens for a developer team. I don't know the limit for certificates though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create at most 2 APNS certificate for each app bundle id you have.
1 for Development and 1 for Production.

---

To create an APNS certificate, you need to choose:

1. Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox) for Development
2. Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) for AppStore/AdHoc

[image: APNS]

---

## Alternate Option

You can even create the certificate by editing an app id.

Check the app id to have the Push Notification capability and then create the certificates from here:

[image: Edit App ID]

Comment: 1 development + 1 production does not seem to be the case anymore. After creating 1 development and 1 production certificate for a specific app id, I still see the "Create Certificate" button on both development and production, implying that I could create _at least_ 2 development and _at least_ 2 production certificates per app id. Possibly more (I haven't tested it).

Comment: @Senseful Thanks for the update. Will check what the deal is now :)